# ASP.NET Core Web API : POST method results in http 400 - bad request

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi

I have an ASP.NET Core Web API with controller endpoints which inserts a single record in my SQL Server database table via a stored procedure:

```cs
public bool Set_PC(string param1, decimal param2, string param3,
                   string param4, string? param5 = null,
                   string? param6 = null, string? param7 = null,
                   string? param8 = null)
{
    try
    {
        var parameters = new[]
            {
                new SqlParameter("@PARAM1", param1),
                new SqlParameter("@PARAM2", param2),
                new SqlParameter("@PARAM3", param3),
                new SqlParameter("@PARAM4", param4),
                new SqlParameter("@PARAM5", (object)param5?? DBNull.Value),
                new SqlParameter("@PARAM6", (object)param6?? DBNull.Value),
                new SqlParameter("@PARAM7", (object)param7?? DBNull.Value),
                new SqlParameter("@PARAM8", (object)param8?? DBNull.Value),
            };

        int rowsAffected = _mydbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw("EXEC SET_PC @PARAM1, @PARAM2, @PARAM3, @PARAM4, @PARAM5, @PARAM6, @PARAM7, @PARAM8", parameters);

        return rowsAffected > 0;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        return false;
    }
}
```

And this is how I call it from a client app

```cs
public async Task<bool> Set_PC(string param1, decimal param2,
                               string param3, string param4,
                               string? param5 = null, string? param6 = null,
                               string? param7 = null, string? param8 = null)
{
    var Payload = new
    {
        param1 = param1,
        param2 = param2,
        param3 = param3,
        param4 = param4,
        param5 = param5,
        param6 = param6,
        param7 = param7,
        param8 = param8
    };

    var Payload_Content = new StringContent(JsonSerializer.Serialize(Payload));

    Uri Set_PC_Endpoint_Uri = new Uri($"http://somepath/somepath/somepath/SetPc");

    try
    {
        HttpResponseMessage Response = await HttpClient.PostAsync(Set_PC_Endpoint_Uri, Payload_Content);

        if (Response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            string Response_Content = await Response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            Check_SetPC_Outcome = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<bool>(Response_Content, JsonSerializerOptions);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(@"\tERROR {0}", ex.Message);
    }

    return Check_SetPC_Outcome;
}
```

Whenever I call the last method from the client, I get a HTTP 400 Bad Request error. This is how I call it:

```
[...] await myhttpService.Set_PC("abc", 745.257, "ok", "175", 
                                 "hello", "ok bye", null, null);
```

I have no idea why it throws that "bad request" exception even though the "packaging" of the values is correct I guess

Comment: You aren't supplying your parameter array `parameters` to `ExecuteSqlRaw`.

Comment: @TimothyG. I've put the parameters variable but I still get the same error of 400 bad request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After my test, you cannot pass the payload directly to a post method without `[FromBody]` attribute, the method cannot get the payload and that’s why you got a 400.

1. Add the parameter
2. Add the `[FromBody]` attribute in your endpoint `Set_PC`
3. Add the format parameters

> a.    Set_PC action (parameter and frombody attribute)

```
[HttpPost(Name = "Set_PC")]
// change 1
public bool Set_PC([FromBody] ParamTest paramTest)
{
    try
    {
        var parameters = new[]
            {
        new SqlParameter("@PARAM1", paramTest.param1),
        new SqlParameter("@PARAM2", paramTest.param2),
        new SqlParameter("@PARAM3", paramTest.param3),
        new SqlParameter("@PARAM4", paramTest.param4),
        new SqlParameter("@PARAM5", (object)paramTest.param5?? DBNull.Value),
        new SqlParameter("@PARAM6", (object)paramTest.param6?? DBNull.Value),
        new SqlParameter("@PARAM7", (object)paramTest.param7?? DBNull.Value),
        new SqlParameter("@PARAM8", (object)paramTest.param8?? DBNull.Value),
    };

         // change 2
        int rowsAffected = _context.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw("EXEC dbo.SET_PC @PARAM1, @PARAM2, @PARAM3, @PARAM4, @PARAM5, @PARAM6, @PARAM7, @PARAM8", parameters);

        return rowsAffected > 0;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        return false;
    }
}
```

> b.    ParamTest Model

```
//control the nullable logic in your model class
// change 3
public class ParamTest
{
    public string param1 { get; set; }
    public decimal param2 { get; set; }
    public string param3 { get; set; }
    public string param4 { get; set; }
    public string? param5 { get; set; } = null;
    public string? param6 { get; set; } = null;
    public string? param7 { get; set; } = null;
    public string? param8 { get; set; } = null;
}
```

> c.    How you call it (add the format parameters)

```
public async Task<bool> Set_PC (string param1, decimal param2,
                       string param3, string param4,
                       string? param5 = null, string? param6 = null,
                       string? param7 = null, string? param8 = null)
{

    var Payload = new
    {
        param1 = param1,
        param2 = param2,
        param3 = param3,
        param4 = param4,
        param5 = param5,
        param6 = param6,
        param7 = param7,
        param8 = param8
    };

    bool Check_SetPC_Outcome = false;
    // change 4
    var Payload_Content = new StringContent(JsonSerializer.Serialize(Payload), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

    Uri Set_PC_Endpoint_Uri = new Uri($"http://somepath/somepath/somepath/SetPc");

    try
    {
        HttpResponseMessage Response = await httpClient.PostAsync(Set_PC_Endpoint_Uri, Payload_Content);

        if (Response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            string Response_Content = await Response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            Check_SetPC_Outcome = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<bool>(Response_Content,new JsonSerializerOptions { });
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(@"\tERROR {0}", ex.Message);
    }

    return Check_SetPC_Outcome;
}
```

Test

[image]

Comment: You don't need to specify `[FromBody]` if you are using a complex type (like a class that represents a JSON structure), but for simple types found in a request body such as `string`, you do.